# SQL Use Subquery results with NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can imagine that question exists in some way, but I haven't found what I was looking for.

I need to remove the found values from the result I'm getting in the main query.

Consider the following:

The mainquery:

```
    SELECT idTable
    FROM tblTables
    WHERE NOT IN idTables = ( **SUBQUERY HERE** )
          AND dtSeats >= 4
    LIMIT 1;
```

The subquery:

```
    SELECT idTable
        FROM tblTables,tblReservation
        WHERE tblTables.idTable = tblReservation.fiTable
        AND fiTime = 1
        AND dtResDate = "2020-06-16"
```

In the tblTables there are idTable and dtSeats.

In the tblReservation are fiTime and dtResDate.

The subquery can get up to three rows.
I need to get the first free table with the lowest number of seats possible.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as tabular text. You should also provide your query as text rather than an image (which we can't copy/paste).

Comment: No; there aren't. Questions this poorly formulated tend to get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the DDL and some sample data would be helpful, but I think what you are looking for is a NOT EXISTS clause. It returns everything in the outer query that doesn't match with a record in the inner query.

```
SELECT idTable
FROM tblTables tt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM tblReservation tr WHERE tt.idTable = tr.idTable AND  
        tr.dtResDate = '2020-06-16'
)
AND dtSeats >= 4
ORDER BY tt.dtSeats
LIMIT 1
```